# Router-link not clickable, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Products from '../views/Products.vue'
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/products',
        name: 'Products',
        component: Products
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router
```

This is my router index.js file and below my app.vue file.

```
   <template>
 <header class="top-bar spread">
      <nav class="top-bar-nav">
        <router-link to="/" class="top-bar-link">
          <i class="icofont-spoon-and-fork"></i>
          <span>Home</span>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/products" class="top-bar-link">
          <span>Products</span>
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/past-orders" class="top-bar-link">
          <span>Past Orders</span>
        </router-link>
      </nav>
      <router-link @click="toggleSidebar" href="#" class="top-bar-cart-link">
        <i class="icofont-cart-alt icofont-1x"></i>
        <span>Cart ({{totalQuantity}})</span>
      </router-link>
    </header>
    <router-view/>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>
```

I'm following a tutorial, can't figure out what I've missed because the links aren't working. I've added the paths in the index file, installed vue-router (this was an issue), but my landing page appears as plain text.

On changing the order of use before mount below, I'm not getting an error:
`const app = createApp(App); app.use(router); app.mount('#app');`

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'options' of '(0 ,
> vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.inject)(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Can you post that here please?

Comment: `/past-orders` doesn't exist on your routes. That will definitely cause an error

Comment: No errors, but there are few warnings. 
`runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: router-link
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: router-view
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>`

Comment: I've not provided any paths or defined the last two router-links yet.

Comment: Is this Vue2 or Vue3?

In Vue2, your HTML needs to be surrounded by a single tag (ie, div)

Comment: vue@3.2.31 - this is the version.

Comment: Please check the edit in the original post.

Comment: Do you have a link to the github this code is at? I'd like to see the entire thing

Comment: Linking it [here](https://github.com/hyang-gi/cart-demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the link to the repo, that really helped me see the issues:

1. You don't have Vue Router installed.

`npm i vue-router`

1. You had some HTML errors in your `App.vue` file. This works:

```
<template>
  <header class="top-bar spread">
    <nav class="top-bar-nav">
      <router-link to="/" class="top-bar-link">
        <i class="icofont-spoon-and-fork"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </router-link>
      <router-link to="/products" class="top-bar-link">
        <span>Products</span>
      </router-link>
      <router-link to="past-orders" class="top-bar-link">
        <span>Past Orders</span>
      </router-link>
      <button @click="toggleSidebar" class="top-bar-cart-link">
        <i class="icofont-cart-alt icofont-1x"></i>
        <span>Cart ({{ totalQuantity }})</span>
      </button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      totalQuantity: 10,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSidebar() {
      console.log("toggling sidebar");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I''ll install it. I used vue add router instead. npm i vue-router didn't work.